# Avro Bengali keyboard switches to Malay (Jawi) after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus-avro

I upgraded one of my machines to Ubuntu 17.04. May be it is related, may be it is not, but for this machine, [Avro Bengali keyboard](https://www.omicronlab.com/avro-keyboard.html) switched to Malay (Jawi) after upgrade.

My other two machines, running Ubuntu 16.04 are working fine.

Please see these self explanatory screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I tried removing and re-adding the keyboard, uninstalling and [reinstalling](http://linux.omicronlab.com/ubuntu_14.04.html) the keyboard without any avail.

Whenever, I switch to Avro keyboard, I get texts in Arabic.

Comment: I installed the thing on my 16.10, and I don't get a keyboard layout chart at all... One thing you may want to do is to install the `ibus-m17n` package and try the Bengali options provided by that package.

Comment: Same issue. It was working on 16.10 but not working on 17.04

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I installed `ibus-m17n`, no improvement. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to happen because of the new XKB symbols file `bn` which was created as a fix of [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94036). As far as I can tell that file is redundant, since the name of the layout - Malay (Jawi) - is already present in the symbols file `my`. Currently there are two entries named Malay (Jawi) in the list of input sources.

Anyway, removing or renaming the `bn` symbols file seems to fix this issue.

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
sudo mv bn bn.bak
```

*Edit:*

I filed [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100701), which has been accepted and will affect version 2.21 of `xkb-data`.

*Edit II:*

The issue is also [about to be fixed](https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/issues/112) in v2 of `ibus-avro`.

---

*Edit III:*

It seems moving the file make wayland session on latest Ubuntu inaccessible. Also the developers of ibus-avro suggested another workaround which fixes the issue without interfering with wayland session. This is documented [here](http://linux.omicronlab.com/2016/09/25/fix-arch-gnome-arabic.html)

In short, you need to edit the file at `/usr/share/ibus/component/ibus-avro.xml`

```
sudo vim /usr/share/ibus/component/ibus-avro.xml
```

On line 20, change

```
<layout>bn</layout>
```

to

```
<layout>us</layout>
```

Save the file and restart your session.

Comment: That fixed it. Who could of imagined such a reason?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I've found a similar bug, mine switches to Arabic instead of Malay. If I move the symbol, then Gnome wayland session breaks. So, I searched and found the fix [here on avro's git repo](https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/issues/112). It fixed the problem nicely!

Comment: @Anwar: Malay (Jawi) is written using an Arabic script, so it's most likely the same issue. Thanks for letting us know that it's about to be fixed in `ibus-avro`.

Comment: You may want to include that information into the answer.

Comment: I think you should focus on [this method](http://linux.omicronlab.com/2016/09/25/fix-arch-gnome-arabic.html) instead, because its from developer and it's non-breaking for wayland session. Currently, your method kicks me out of wayland

Comment: @Anwar: Please feel free to edit the answer in that direction. You are using the thing, after all. ;) (Hopefully the problem will go away in 18.04 with an update of `xkb-data`.)

Answer (score 0):

This does solve the problem:  https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro

You can try out my script which automatically fetches everything and installs avro for you. Just download or clone my repository: https://github.com/pavakpaul/ibus-avro-installer-for-ubuntu and execute install-ibus-avro-for-ubuntu-wily.sh