# How to install ibus-avro in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: fonts, 17.04, language-support, ibus-avro

This question is very similar to [the question asked here.](https://askubuntu.com/q/764706/127036) In fact, this is the way I installed Avro earlier.

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 in a new laptop, and followed the same process given in the link. However, after installing (and following the steps) the font is not showing up as Bengali. In n fact, it started typing in Arabic!

Any idea what went wrong? I have followed all the processes multiple times.

Comment: Describe the steps you followed to install ibus. There were two answers. Did you restart after installation?  And were you using Unity or GNOME?

Comment: I tested it in 17.04 and worked perfectly. You need to restart the pc or `ibus-daemon` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of a bug in avro. I don't know what causes the bug, but to fix this, open your terminal and follow these steps:

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols


sudo mv bn bn.bak
```

So, the first command will change your direcory to "/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols". And the second command will rename the file named "bn".

Thanks!!!

Comment: "This happens" what happens? I tested it in 17.04 and worked perfectly!

Comment: @Anwar: The bug is real for those who have encountered it, but it seems to have been [fixed in master](https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/commit/7561784899fa42df9d9f677a14a6dcd2c55081c7). If it worked for you: 1. Which version of the `xkb-data` package are you using, and 2. How did you install `ibus-avro`?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson In 17.04, `xkb-data` version is 2.19*. In 16.04 it is 2.16. It's working in both platform without any problem. I think OP didn't restart or didn't tell us everything. There might be something wrong with his configuration which may have been skipped from the description

Comment: @Anwar: Ok. I could reproduce the problem a month ago, which led me to answer the [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903961/avro-bengali-keyboard-switches-to-malay-jawi-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-04).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson That's interesting. Let us see what OP has to tell